# how to displaying pivot in matrix reporting service?

Tags: service, reporting, matrix, pivot

I have problem relating to pivot query and matrix reporting. I don't know how to display it on matrix reporting service so it will dynamic column. Can any body help me to show how to configure the matrix table? or could you give the link where can I find the answer of my problem? I'm newbie in reporting service.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a matrix control as a 'design time pivot table'

Once it has been designed and it has rendered the data, the output is fixed - you cannot drag and drop like you would with a pivot table.

The matrix control can have dynamic row/column groupings which will grow with your data.

It's pretty easy to use once you get your head around the concept of 'inscope'

To create dynamic columns, you just need to create a column grouping (towards the top right section of the matrix control once you have dragged it on to the form) Just tell it which field to use as a grouping.